# Add emaillink to author column

Tags: document-library

I got a document libary with the column "author". I would like to link the authors name, with his email adress. Is this possible? And how can i do this?!

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OOB **Created By** column would in theory be equivalent to the author in most cases, unless there is some bulk operation placing the documents in the library.  If **Created By** won't work then you can put the **Author** in a **Person/Group** field, where the value presented in that field will link to their profile, including email if available.

Comment: The problem is: Author is a choice list column and Created By doesn't work here. The next problem that the document often has multiple authors.

Comment: You can specify multiple persons in a Person/Group field and limit what's presented in "Select People" dialog to a specific group.  So create a group called Authors in SharePoint, add the folks from the dropdown, and then use a Person/Group field instead of Multi-Choice.

Comment: I did that, but "You are only allowed to enter one item." if i try to name him multiple authors for one document. And have to rebuild a database and will mostly copy the documents, so i cant upload all manually, but there is no way to get authors name automatically as an email adress or?

Comment: Okay found the problem with allow multiple :) sorry im very new to sharepoint. but any solution for the auto email stuff?

Comment: You need to set "Allow multiple selections" to Yes on the column, that will get rid of the "You are only allowed to enter one item" message.  This is the best solution I can come up with...you're just not going to be able to do what you want to do with a Choice List.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by auto email stuff.  With the Person/Group field the names are presented as links to the person's profile or you have the option in the configuration for the Person/Group field to display the email.

Comment: Meant just to do it automatically but u already said it isnt possible, okay my last problem is: I created a Datasheet view, with the column "Author" as Person/Group, works, if i click on the arrow , he shows me all user not only the ones in the group authors. Is it possible just showing the Users in the Group Authors? Thanks !